# CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder doesn't exist

Tags: .net, globalization

Okay, this is a strange one.

I'm trying to create a custom culture using:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

var x = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder();
```

But I get the nasty red Resharper error with no options.

The type or namespace name 'CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Globalization'

What's going on, am I missing something? Can't find any help on google...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `sysglobl.dll`. This is already installed in the GAC as `sysglobl`.

For future reference, if you check the MSDN page for [CultureAndRegionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) you can see that it says

> Namespace:  `System.Globalization`
>
> Assembly:  `sysglobl` (in `sysglobl.dll`)

The issue is that namespaces can be spread across different assemblies (for example, `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` lives in `mscorlib`.)

Comment: Thanks. I did see that, but when I was looking for the assembly to add, I was looking for "System.Globalization" ... I missed "sysglobal" in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Jason is correct.

To add the `sysglobl.dll` reference:

1. In `Solution Explorer`, right click on your project's `References`
2. Click `Add Reference...`
3. Type `sysglobl` in the search box in the upper right-hand corner
4. Check the box
5. Click `OK`

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Jason's answer, if like me you're working with a web site, and not a web project, just add to your web.config, under the the tags `system.web` => `compilation` => `assemblies`:

```
<add assembly="sysglobl, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```