# Change date picker text: capitalize month

Tags: c#, datepicker

I want to change the date picker by upper-casing the first letter of the month.

Currently I'm using the *set culture info* in the thread and specify the format there, but for my culture the month is always all lowercase:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "ddd dd/MMM/yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Displays:

```
Dom 19/ago/2012
```

And I would like to have:

```
Dom 19/Ago/2012
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying the `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames`, `AbbreviatedMonthNames` along with the `ShortDatePattern` did the trick.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX")
{
    DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
    {
        AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = new string[] { "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic", string.Empty },
        AbbreviatedMonthNames         = new string[] { "Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic", string.Empty },
        ShortDatePattern = "ddd dd/MMM/yyyy"
    }
};
```

Yields:

[image]

Edit:

I have to add:

```
...
AbbreviatedDayNames = new string[] { "Dom",  "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb"},
```

Too

Comment: Doh.. it says: `Sun 18/Ago/2012` not `Dom 19/Ago/2012` I have to add `AbbreviatedDayNames` too

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the [`CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) to copy the existing culture and change only the month names. Then you subsequently use that culture in your application instead of the `CultureInfo` you now use.

Note however, that `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder` is in the `sysglobl.dll` assembly, [which you'll need to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088126/cultureandregioninfobuilder-doesnt-exist).

Comment: Didn't need ( couldn't ) use that class, but instead I specify the `AbbreviatedMonthNames` property